# making a 13 digit random number generator in Java

Tags: java

a friend of mine at Uni, was wanting to generate a bunch of 13 digit numbers so he can test his sorting algorithms on, but was doing it a very long way around, so i've tried to use the following code to generate a settable number of 13 digit numbers.

```
public class random {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    long intArray[] = new long[20]; // to generate more than 20 random numbers increase this and the 'i < 20' to the same number ie. 75 

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) { // here
        intArray[i] = numbGen();            
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < intArray.length; j++) {
        System.out.println(intArray[j]);
    }

}

public static long numbGen() {

    long numb = (long)(Math.random() * 10000000 * 1000000); // had to use this as int's are to small for a 13 digit number.

    return numb;
}
}
```

my issue is now sometimes it will generate a couple of 12 digit numbers in the group of 20 and i want to find a way not to add the number to the array if it is not 13 digits. I've tried if statement but getting stuck on not being able to determine the length (individual characters) of the Long.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: why wont you create a string of 13 digits and parse it to BigInteger?

Comment: Actually, your method generates 14 digit numbers

Comment: How do you create a string of randomly generated numbers, and haven't heard of a BigInteger. I will look that up

Comment: whoops 1 too many 0's, thank you @Arash - but it still will generate some numbers with only 12 digits and the rest 13, without that extra 0

Comment: See my answer Steve, in my solution you don't need to make any tests, it will be the fastest and most elegant solution to your problem.

Comment: Note that a double only has 15 to 17 significant decimal digits precision. Generating a random with 13 decimal digits by simple multiplication is rather dangerous and *may* give a non-uniform random space - god forbid that somebody extends the range to 17 or 18 digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution for the problem that you described:

```
public static long numbGen() {
    while (true) {
        long numb = (long)(Math.random() * 100000000 * 1000000); // had to use this as int's are to small for a 13 digit number.
        if (String.valueOf(numb).length() == 13)
            return numb;
    }
}
```

This is not the most efficient or most random implementation of generating a 13-digit number but it answers *your* specific question.

Comment: Can you indicate if the double returned by `Math.random()` doesn't influence he randomness with regards to precission?

Comment: i tried a few ways to do this "String.valueOf(numb).length() == 13" but couldn't get it write and was driving me crazy.

Comment: Downvoted as my concern about the precision has not been answered; this trick may not result in a truly random distribution.

Comment: @owlstead I copied the authors code and addressed his actual question: how to determine how many digits there are in a number. If you have a concern about the call to `Math.random`, address it to the OP, not to me.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt At stackoverflow we should try and create reuseable answers, not just go with whatever the OP tells us and provide a quick "fix" some source code. Besides, I did address this to the OP as well, in the comments section.

Answer (score 6):

A simple solution:

```
    while(test < 10000) {
        long num = (long) (Math.random() * 100000000 * 1000000);
        if(Long.toString(num).length() == 13) {
            return num;
        }
        test++;
    }
```

However, a better solution is this:

```
long number = (long) Math.floor(Math.random() * 9000000000000L) + 1000000000000L;
```

This will only generate random 13 digit numbers, and you don't need to check if there are more or less digits.

Note that this solution may not scale to a higher number of digits and may not return a perfect distribution of random numbers.

Comment: The latter answer may also have less issues with regards to the precision than the earlier "simple solution", but I would not bet on it that it does not have *any* issues.

Comment: If you find any issues please tell, I can't see any in regards to this problem...

Comment: If you create a random double then it will have 15-17 bits precision. Each time you multiply it you will have to assign the number into a specific discrete number. Now if the number is large enough you get into trouble; maybe 100 doubles values map to value 1, 101 to value 2 and 99 to value 3. This means that your random distribution is almost but not quite perfect. Of course, if you have 1 or less double values to map to a certain number (e.g. what happens for 18 digits) then you won't even generate some specific values.

Comment: Minimalistic example: the double would range from `0` to `1` with steps of `0.1` and you would apply it to generate a number from `0` to `4` by multiplying with 4. You would have to map 10 possible outcomes (0.1, 0.2 etc.) to 4 integers. That is of course not possible. Now imagine what happens if you have to map it to `0` to `40` :)

Answer (score 4):

```
long min = 1000000000000L; //13 digits inclusive
long max = 10000000000000L; //14 digits exclusive
Random random = new Random()
long number = min+((long)(random.nextDouble()*(max-min)));
```

Comment: @DavidWallace yeah I was half way to changing

Comment: This is the correct way to do it.  And it's also simpler than any other answer so far.

Comment: This answer has *less* issues with regards to double precision than calling an integer multiplication twice, but it *may* still have issues with regards to random distributions. It won't scale to a higher number of digits for sure.

Answer (score 2):

A generic integer based implementation would be:

```
public static long randomDigits(int digits) {
    if (digits <= 0 || digits > 18) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("A long can store the random of 18 full digits, you required: " + digits);
    }

    // use SecureRandom instead for truly random values
    final Random r = new Random();
    long randomNumber = r.nextInt(9) + 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < digits; i++) {
        randomNumber = randomNumber * 10L + (long) r.nextInt(10);
    }
    return randomNumber;
}
```

or use a shorter version for 13 digits that does not tax the RNG as much:

```
public static long thirteenRandomDigits() {
    final Random r = new Random();
    return 1_000_000_000L * (r.nextInt(9_000) + 1_000)
            + r.nextInt(1_000_000_000);
}
```

---

These solutions are better to using `Math.random()` because they don't rely on multiplication with a large number to generate the random values. A double only has 15-17 digits precision, which is very close to the 13 digits number it is multiplied with. This leads to unequal distributions of random numbers. Solutions based on `Math.random()` won't scale past 13 digits either.

Comment: Note that it is rather strange to request a random number that *has* to start with a value from 1 to 9. Normally that's only used if the value needs to be stored or shown as string in decimal number format.

Comment: This is far and away the cleanest, most correct implementation of the actual requirements.  Implementations using `Math.random()` are potentially biased, especially with the size of the range we're talking about.

Comment: I don't mind downvotes, but please explain what is wrong with this solution, as I currently would not know what the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

[ThreadLocalRandom](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html) is a good thing, introduced in Java 1.7

```
java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom
    .current()
    .nextLong(1000000000000L, 10000000000000L);
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, a Long doesn't have characters.

If you want to see if it has 13 digits, compare it to 999999999999L.

If you want to insure you have a value w/ 13 digits, get a random number between 0 and 8999999999999L (inclusive) (using the technique you already have to generate a random number in a range) and add it to 1000000000000L.

Comment: first digit is always 1. doesnt seem really random.

Comment: OK, of course, now indicate how you would get a random long in that range.

Answer (score 0):

```
long randomNumber = 0;
long power = 1;

for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++) { // up to 12 not 13
    Random r = new Random();
    int randomInt = r.nextInt(10);

    randomNumber += (power * randomInt);
    power *= 10;
}

// here, the most stupid way to provide last digit to be not zero
Random r = new Random();
int randomInt = r.nextInt(9);
randomInt++;

randomNumber += (power * randomInt);
power *= 10;
```

Comment: for the last digit it must be checked whether its zero

Comment: In other words, it doesn't solve the original problem, right?

Comment: @DavidWallace True, but I would consider this a much more valid method of generating the random, and it is very easily fixed.

Comment: if you want spoon in your mouth to feed, yes it does not solve. we are here to give ideas. not to write whole code. i dont need to write every simple if condition here.

Comment: Sure, but you didn't answer the question.  Your so-called solution is equivalent to the original problem.  The question is "how do I knock out the 12-digit numbers", not "what's a different way of doing exactly what I'm already doing".

Answer (score 0):

Why not we try with Unix timestamp in milliseconds.Because that will work for next 200 years and after that we need to only eliminate the trailing digit from the number.

```
Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
```

and by using this method we don't need any loop or any condition and it will give me a unique number every time.